# Using Ajax with Isotope

Tags: ajax, jquery-isotope

I am trying to append items to an Isotope based div, and the items are getting appended, but the appended items are not taking the Css (i.e.they are misplaced). The following is my html & ajax function:

```
div class="main_isotop" id="container"

var grid = $('.main_isotop').isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.item',
                    layoutMode: 'masonry'
                });
$.ajax({

                    url: '/loadmoremedia',
                    type: 'GET',
                    datatype: 'html',
                    data: {
                        }                        },
                    success: function (result) {
                        //var $items = result;
                        $('#lastPhotoId').remove();
                        //$('.main_isotop').append(result);
                        grid.append(result)
                            // add and lay out newly appended elements
                            .isotope('appended', result);
                        processing = false;
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Failed");
                    }
                });
```

Can anyone point out what is missing? Modifications are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope has many [methods](http://isotope.metafizzy.co.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/methods.html) for calculating the layout after dynamically adding new content with ajax etc..

You can try something like this

`$container.isotope('insert', $items)`

OR

`$container.append( $html );
 $container.isotope( 'appended', $html );`

All the best. :-)

Comment: Where to use insert ?

Comment: These are methods of isotope, You can refer the link and try once. If possible, can you create a fiddle, so that we can do changes on that.